# How to create vast tag with javascript ad code creative

Tags: javascript, video, ads, vast

How can I (via Google's DFP or any other method) generate VAST ad tags for  javascript ad code, so I can show the ad as pre-roll or mid-roll on videos.

my player supports only vast tags ... so I can not integrate javaspcrit ad codes with it directly.

basically, I want to ad my ad network to DFP so DFP creates the VAST tag and handled this creative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to [VPAID](https://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VPAID_2_0_Final_04-10-2012.pdf) if you are talking about javascript ads?

Integrating VPAID from scratch can be a complex proces, because the spec specifies a lot of technical requirements for both the player and the ad unit.

There are several ways you can tackle this:

- Either you write the functionality on your own (which can take a while)
- OR you make an integration with [Google IMA](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/). They have a [custom API](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/quickstart) where you can integrate with.
- OR you use a player that supports VPAID or has an integration with Google IMA, such as [THEOplayer](https://www.theoplayer.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use create a Ad Unit with Video Vast sizes as shown below.

[image: Create Video Ad Unit]

Generate the tags of that ad unit which will show the options. Choose "Google Publisher tag for video"

[image: Generate Tags]

It will give you a VAST tag which you have to pass it in video player you are using, e.g. VideoJS and IMA player.

Create a creative template to enable you write the video player code which will pass the video VAST tag as a macro shown below.

[image]

While creating a creative you can select this template from "User Defined Template" from the DFP Creative Section.

Hope this helps!